# тикающим часам добавить мигающие двоеточия(1 секунда - есть :, 2 секунда - нет, 3 секунда - есть, 4 - нет)

Tags: javascript

```
    let now = new Date();
    let year = now.getFullYear(); // 2018
    let month = now.getMonth(); // от 0 (январь) до 11
    let date = now.getDate(); // 15
    let day = now.getDay(); // 0 - воскресенье    6

    const d = document.querySelector('.data');
    //d.innerHTML = date + '.' + month + '.' + year; // 15.12.2018, суббота
    d.innerHTML = `${date}.${month+1}.${year}, ${days[day]}`;

    let hours = now.getHours(); // 0-23
    let min = now.getMinutes(); // 0-59
    let sec = now.getSeconds(); // 0-59
    let ms = now.getMilliseconds(); // 0-1000

    const q = document.querySelector('.time');

    /*if(min <10 )
    {
        min='0'+min;
    }

    if(sec <10 )
    {
        sec='0'+sec;
    }*/

    function format(n) {
        /*if(n < 10 )
        {
            return '0'+n;
        }
        else
        {
            return n;
        }*/
        return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n; // условие?если условие true : если условие false
    }
    q.innerHTML = `${hours}:${format(min)}:${format(sec)}:${ms}`;

    const dop = document.querySelector('.dop');
    //dop.innerHTML = now.toString();
    //dop.innerHTML = now.toLocaleString();
    //dop.innerHTML = now.toUTCString();
    dop.innerHTML = now.getTime();

    const timetik = document.querySelector('.timetik');

    setInterval( showTime , 1);

    function showTime(){
        let now = new Date();
        let hours = now.getHours(); // 0-23
        let min = now.getMinutes(); // 0-59
        let sec = now.getSeconds(); // 0-59
        let ms = now.getMilliseconds(); // 0-1000
        //если сек не четная,
        timetik.innerHTML = `${hours}:${format(min)}:${format(sec)}:${ms}`;
        //иначе 
        timetik.innerHTML = `${hours} ${format(min)} ${format(sec)} ${ms}`;

    }
```

Comment: Думаю простым решением будет CSS анимация длительностью 1 секунда, это будет самым оптимальным решением с точки зрения производительности

Comment: надо на js,как сделать,чтоб двоеточие одну сек ,выводилось,вторую нет

Comment: `sec%2 ? ":" : " "`

Comment: в какую строчку это вставить?

Comment: Я с телефона поэтому так кратко) Если до конца дня никто не сделает то к вечеру сформирую ответ.

Comment: (((жаль,мне код через час сдать надо

Comment: В функцию showTime(), timeTick.innerHTML = sec%2 ? "выражение с двоеточием" : "выражение без двоеточия"

Comment: Ну как? timetick вместо timeTick

Comment: timetik.innerHTML = `${hours}:${format(min)}:${format(sec)}:${ms}`;

   //иначе 
   timetik.innerHTML = `${hours} ${format(min)} ${format(sec)} ${ms}`;

Comment: Да вроде так, работает?

Comment: как реализовать ,вот это?чтоб одну сек,была одна строчка,другую вторая

Comment: //если сек не четная,одна строка,если четная другая

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const timetik = document.querySelector('#timetik');

const format = (n) => n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;

const showTime = () => {
  let now = new Date();
  let hours = now.getHours(); // 0-23
  let min = now.getMinutes(); // 0-59
  let sec = now.getSeconds(); // 0-59
  let ms = now.getMilliseconds(); // 0-1000

  timetik.innerHTML = sec%2 ? `${hours}:${format(min)}:${format(sec)}:${ms}` : `${hours} ${format(min)} ${format(sec)} ${ms}`;
}

setInterval(showTime, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="timetik"></span>
```

Comment: супер!! то что надо

Comment: С телефона это тот ещё челендж) Пожалуйста

Comment: к вам можно,по таким мелким вопросам обращаться?

Comment: Ну, stackoverflow а там уже я / не я, ответ будет

Comment: При клике по блоку он начинает плавно исчезать. Изменение стиля opacity=1,затем=0

Comment: как реализовать функцию? допустим class(.block)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   window.onload = function(){
   var now = new Date();
 window.setInterval(function(){
      now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds()+1);
       var clock = document.getElementById("clock");
       var h,m;
       h=now.getHours();
       m=now.getMinutes();
       s=now.getSeconds();
       var dd = " ";
       if(s%2==0)dd=":";
     clock.innerHTML = (h<10?'0'+h:h)+dd+(m<10?'0'+m:m);
 }, 1000);
};
</script>
```

туда где нужны часики: `<cl id="clock"></cl>`

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```js
   window.onload = function(){
 var now = new Date();
 window.setInterval(function(){
      now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds()+1);
       var clock = document.getElementById("clock");
       var h,m;
       h=now.getHours();
       m=now.getMinutes();
       var dd = "<span class=blink>:</span>";
     clock.innerHTML = (h<10?'0'+h:h)+dd+(m<10?'0'+m:m);
 }, 1000);
};
```

```css
.blink {
    animation: blink 1s infinite; /* Параметры анимации */
   }
   @keyframes blink {
    0% { opacity: 1; /* Непрозрачный текст */ }
    50% { opacity: 0; /* Прозрачный текст */ }
    100% { opacity: 1; /* Непрозрачный текст */ }
   }
```

```html
<div id=clock></div>
```